# How to convert ISO 8601 string to local date time

Tags: java, android

how do I convert something like this 2018-03-08T08:30:00.000Z to 'March 8 2016'  or '8. März 2016' (german)

Comment: General answers are in duplicate targets (you may need to refresh this page to see them at top of your question). If you will have more specific problem with using solutions described there [edit] your question and describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: @Pshemo I don't see how my question is not specific enough. I literally don't know how to do the thing that I described above and the questions you marked as duplicate don't help me with my problem at all.

Comment: I didn't say your question is not specific. But in current form it is combination of two duplicates linked above. My comment was meant to be information that *if* you will have some problems with solutions mentioned in duplicates you *can* edit your question and describe that problems, precisely so we could avoid "...don't help me with my problem at all". What you want is convert date in one string format to another (which is explained in first duplicate) but second format should use specific locale (like German, which is explained in second duplicate).